# Matplotlib suddenly crashes after reinstalling Xcode?

Tags: python, xcode, numpy, matplotlib

I was happy in my world of python and matplotlib with a good level of familiarity. I notied Xcode on my Mac wasn't working so I installed the latest version from Apple and it somehow broke my install of matplotlib (or numpy?)! I'm now getting

```
...
/sw/lib/python2.5/site-packages/matplotlib-0.91.1-py2.5-macosx-
10.5-i386.egg/matplotlib/numerix/ma/__init__.py in <module>()
     14         print "using maskedarray"
     15     else:
---> 16         from numpy.core.ma import *
     17         #print "using ma"
     18     def getmaskorNone(obj):

ImportError: No module named ma
```

I've tried reinstalling numpy (Ver 1.3.0) and matplotlib (Ver 0.91.1) to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You're using Python from Fink, so Xcode doesn't have anything to do with it.  `from numpy.core.ma import *` works fine with Apple's bundled Python and NumPy too.

Comment: The bundled python was deleted for... another conflict quite a while ago. I suppose I'll have to reinstall from developers DVD.

Comment: Yeah, don't do that.  Leave /System, /usr, etc. alone.  Portions of OS X itself (such as faxing) *require* the bundled Python to work.